# In iOS, is it possible to open notifications directly in customized mode?

Tags: ios, notifications

iOS provides for custom push notifications in mobile devices, however they are implemented by first opening a default notification, if the user taps it, then an event is sent to open the custom notification.

In the example below, the left one is the default notification, the right one is the custom one displayed after tapping the default.

[image: example of default vs. custom iOS notifications]

I'm wondering if there is a way to open the custom notification directly with no user interaction?

Comment: Even if this *was* possible, wouldn't automatically having an application open without the user's direct consent be horrible user experience? Or am I mis-understanding your question?

Comment: @esqew – could argue it would be a better user experience since it would remove the need to open a second notification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think there is a way to open the custom notification by default or render the custom notification as a default notification.

As per [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/customizing_the_appearance_of_notifications?language=objc), when the device receives a push, it displays the alert in 2 stages

- First, an abbreviated banner with the title, subtitle, and two to four lines of body text from the notification
- If the user presses the abbreviated banner, it displays the full notification interface, including any notification-related actions.

And it clearly states

> The **system provides the interface for the abbreviated banner**, but you
>   can customize the full interface using a notification content app
>   extension.

So I dont think there is a way to display a custom notification UI without the user action.

But if you absolutely want to display an media in the notification, you can use [UNNotificationAttachment](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationattachment?language=objc) to display the media elements like image, audio, and video in the system alert itself.

Answer (score -1):

@RameshVel answer is correct. Here is sample and tutorial for doing this.

> https://www.appcoda.com/user-notifications-ios12/